# How to resolve this Mediapipe TypeError?

Tags: python, computer-vision, typeerror, importerror, mediapipe

Exception has occurred: TypeError
Descriptors cannot not be created directly.
If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.
If you cannot immediately regenerate your protos, some other possible workarounds are:

1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).

More information: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/news/2022-05-06#python-updates
File "C:\STUFF\Code\Computer Vision\HandTrackingMin.py", line 2, in 
import mediapipe as mp
This is the debugger output. How to resolve this?

The code is:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
hands = mpHands.Hands()
mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

pTime = 0
cTime = 0

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = hands.process(imgRGB)

    if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
        for handLms in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms, mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        
    cTime = time.time()
    fps = 1/(cTime-pTime)
    pTime = cTime

    cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10,70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255,0,255), 3)

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
pip install protobuf<=3.20.1 --force-reinstall
```

it should solve the error.

Greetings